# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Compilación de iOS - Genexus 17 U9 Smart Devices

Tags: ios, genexus

Buen día,
Al intentar hacer Build All o Rebuild All después de actualizar a Genexus 17 U9 se presenta el error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, Failed: iOS Compilation

Estoy utilizando generador .Net

Se actualizó ya a Xcode 13.4.

[image: Detalles del error]

¿A alguien le ha surgido este inconveniente?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.